# C# Selenium. Не получается нажать на кнопку

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium

Создаю приложение, в котором требуется мне взять базу с Avito, на нужной [страничке](https://m.avito.ru/abakan/predlozheniya_uslug/krasota_zdorove) имеется кнопка

`<div class="DnHhI"><span class="_2bexo">Загрузить еще</span></div>`

Появляется она после нескольких прокрутов.

Прокручиваю страницу с помощью 
`((IJavaScriptExecutor)chr).ExecuteScript("var timeId=setInterval(function(){window.scrollY<document.body.scrollHeight-window.screen.availHeight?window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight):(clearInterval(timeId),window.scrollTo(0,0))},500);");`

Пытался нажать с помощью:

```
chr.FindElement(By.XPath("span[@class='_2bexo']").Click();
```

И

```
chr.FindElement(By.XPath("div[@class='DnHhI']").Click();
```

А также

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)chr).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", chr.FindElement(By.XPath("span[@class='_2bexo']")));
```

Ну и

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)chr).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", chr.FindElement(By.XPath("div[@class='DnHhI']")));
```

В каждом из случаев приложение зацикливается на клике по кнопке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем твоим xpath не хватает `//`

Твой:

```
chr.FindElement(By.XPath("span[@class='_2bexo']").Click();
```

А должно быть:

```
chr.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='_2bexo']").Click();
```

и т.д., но лучше использовать xpath с текстом:

```
chr.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[.='Загрузить еще']").Click();
```

Или:

```
//div[@data-marker="items"]/div[last()]/span
```

Или, как пример, можно использовать css selectorы:

```
div[data-marker="items"] > div:last-child span

[data-marker="items"] > div:nth-child(2) span
```

Comment: Sers, зло делаешь ему ты. Услугой медвежей ответ является твой. И боком вылезет в будущем ему помощь твоя.

Comment: @Andrew надеюсь он использует селекторы, как примеры для дальнейшего обучения.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно указать нормальный xpath или CssSelector. Ты пытаешся использовать поиск по названию автоматически генеррированного имени класса (судя по названию класса).

А это тебе маловероятно что принесет достаточно хорошую воспроизводимость/стабильность кода.

Как выглядит адекватный xpath?

```
chr.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@data-marker='items']/div/div/../span").Click();
//это я рандомно из головы написал, просто влом разбиратся с структурой страницы
```

Да и вообще разберись нормально с [синтаксисом xpath](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14)-а. Это очень облегчает жизнь в целом. Твоя проблема в даном вопросе именно в том что ты не умеешь писать хорошие селекторы. **А писать их вместо тебя -- это плохая идея. Ты банально ничему не научишся. Это один из основных навыков при работе с селениумом.**

Comment: Надо написать xpath целиком? Просто, как я понял, он находит первый элемент подобного класса, классы на страничке постоянные, после обновления остаются теми же. В любом случае, сейчас попробую, спасибо

Comment: нет, надо писать икспас максимально коротко и обязательно относительный а не абсолютный (вот та точка со слешем на начале). Так же не привязыватся к автоматически генерируемым названиям класса, если привязыватся, то только к человекочитаемым названиям. Если возможно - не использовать те ".." ибо это нагружает поиск. Но иногда без этого не обойтись. Разбирайся с синтаксисом, короче. И до тебя достаточно быстро прийдет понимание того каким должен быть хороший икспас.

Comment: Относительный там не получится, не от чего отталкиваться

Comment: не верю. Не встречал ни единого случая что бы не можно было воспользоватся относительным,

Comment: В основном использую подобный вид 'page.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='_1Jm7J']")).Text;' запросов, но ведь надо от чего-то отталкиваться, от абсолютного, нет?

Comment: отталкивайся, например, от `.//div[@data-marker='items']/` или, например, от `.//div[@id='app']/div[3]/` . Вот тебе и красивая относительная привязка.

Comment: если использовать такие икспасы как ты написал, то твои тесты с критической вероятностью нужно будет постоянно поддерживать а так же снизится читабельность кода. Если же это не тесты а некая апликуха для кравлинга данных, то при малейшем изменении на сайте это все дело просто посыпется. И мало того что оно посыпется, так еще и будет сложно разобрать что же эта команда вообще делала. Короче, не нужно писать такие икспасы. Таким ты делаешь зло как себе, так и тем, кто с твоим кодом будет иметь дело.